# How to fill object from contents of a string and populate a List?

Tags: c#, string, http, gzip

I have a string that I have sent through a HTTP Web Request compressing with GZIP with the following data:

```
[Route("Test")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
 var data = "[0].meetingDate=2019-07-12&[0].courseId=12&[0].raceNumber=1&[0].horseCode=000000331213&[1].meetingDate=2019-07-12&[1].courseId=12&[1].raceNumber=1&[1].horseCode=000000356650";

  try
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44374/HorseRacingApi/Prices/GetPriceForEntries");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            var dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            using (var requestDS = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(requestDS, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    zipStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                }

                requestDS.Flush();
            }
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Debug.WriteLine("Response stream received.");
        Debug.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();

        return Ok("Sent!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I am receiving the http data in this function and decompressing it:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetPriceForEntries")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public JsonResult GetPriceForEntries(bool? ShowAll)
{
    string contents = null;

    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(Request.Body, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (StreamReader unzip = new StreamReader(zip))
        {
            contents = unzip.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }


   //CONVERT CONTENTS TO LIST HERE?

    return Json("GOT");
}
```

I have a object/model setup:

```
public class JsonEntryKey
{
    public DateTime meetingDate { get; set; }
    public int courseId { get; set; }
    public int raceNumber { get; set; }
    public string horseCode { get; set; }
}
```

How do I convert this 'string' to the List object above?

The reason I am sending this data by compressing is because sometimes the data will be very big.

Cheers

EDIT: Here is my attempt at creating my owner 'Converter'

```
 //Convert string to table.
        string[] unzipString = contents.Split('=','&');
        List<Core.Models.JsonEntryKey> entries = new List<Core.Models.JsonEntryKey>();

        for (int i = 1; i < entries.Count; i += 8)
        {
            DateTime meetingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(entries[i]);
            int courseId = int.Parse(unzipString[i + 2]);
            int raceNumber = int.Parse(unzipString[i + 4]);
            string horseCode = unzipString[i + 6];

            entries.Add(new Core.Models.JsonEntryKey
            {
                meetingDate = meetingDate,
                courseId = courseId,
                raceNumber = raceNumber,
                horseCode = horseCode
            });
        }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: First you have to take the needed information out of your string. For example with regex. Then you can create your list.  Mabye you can try to split it by [0] so you have only the property name and the value.

Comment: Are you limited in any way to send that list in a JSON format? If yes, you have to make a custom converter.

Comment: What is the exact information you need from this string? You cannot convert this string directly to a List without a custom converter.

Comment: As adSad said, why no JSON format? Also what have you tried and where are your problems exaclty?

Comment: I have updated my question. If we could convert the data string to JSON string and send by json and then convert to list I could?

Comment: Is there an example of regex doing this? Wouldnt regex be ineffecient?

Comment: What client side library are you using to encode the form data?

Comment: have you tried to parse the string at all? even without regex? may be using a `data.Split` ?

Comment: @Mong Zhu How would I split the data, as in which points would i be splitting it at?

Comment: start with `'&'`, group by `[0]`, use reflection to populate the object

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci I have tried a regex parse for trial basis for your string. If you are interested to see the regex parsing, here is the link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4jYteV

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci After doing some reading I found [this Phil Haack post](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) about MVC2 expression-based helpers which output this format. It suggests that the default model binder will bind this stuff automatically if you just make your method parameter type `ICollection<JsonEntryKey>`. This should also have the advantage that you don't need to manually unzip the request body.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma looks good, but does it work as effecient as doing it the way ive done?

Comment: @dezfowler I have done this previously, but it seems to crash when the data string is big.

Comment: Crashes with what error? There are restrictions on request size and the .NET model binding may also have some protection against big requests.

Comment: @dezfowler sometimes the data can be 47k in length, and a 500 error.

Comment: That's not particularly big, especially if it's being gzipped. Might be worth checking your logs to see what the actual error is that caused the 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the basic parsing can be done in 3 steps.

1) [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) the entire string by `'&'`

```
string [] parts = data.Split('&')
```

you end up with the sigle parts:

> `[0].meetingDate=2019-07-12` 
>   `[0].courseId=12` 
>   `[0].raceNumber=1` 
>   `[0].horseCode=000000331213` 
>   `[1].meetingDate=2019-07-12` 
>   `[1].courseId=12` 
>   `[1].raceNumber=1` 
>   `[1].horseCode=000000356650`

2) now you can [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) the number in the parenthesis, since it seems to denote the index of the object `[0]` , `[1]`, .... Split by the `'.'` and take the first element:

```
var items = parts.GroupBy(x => x.Split('.').First());
```

3) now for each group (which is basically a collection of property information about each object) you need to iterate through the properties, find the corresponding property via reflection and set the value. In the end: don't forget to collect your newly created objects into a collection:

```
List<JsonEntryKey> collection = new List<JsonEntryKey>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var entry = new JsonEntryKey();
    foreach (var property in item)
    {
        // here the position propInfo[1] has the property name and propInfo[2] has the value
        string [] propInfo = property.Split(new string[] {"].", "="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // extract here the corresponding property information  
        PropertyInfo info = typeof(JsonEntryKey).GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name == propInfo[1]);
        info.SetValue(entry, Convert.ChangeType(propInfo[2], info.PropertyType));
    }       
    collection.Add(entry);      
}
```

The outcome from your string looks in a LINQPad Dump like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done something similar I have updated my post. I am guessing your way is much better than mine?

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci "much better" I really don't know. depends on the point of view how to assess it. I guess my solution is less dependent on the squence order of the properties inside your string. if the order might change one day, then hard coded indices like in your solution will not work anymore. I merely used the fact that you named the properties in your class exactly as they appear in the string

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci I guess if you would have posted all this code in the beginning, you would have saved you all these downvotes, probably.... but on a second thought, people on SO really like to downvote :D

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that I wanted to share is a `Regex` based one. The regular expression that I have built for this string will work after appending the `&` character at the end of the string and based on the regex logic, the required data will be parsed out from the string. This is just an example of how you can use regular expressions for handling string scenarios. Regarding the performance as per the official specs:

> The regular expression engine in .NET is a powerful, full-featured tool that processes text based on pattern matches rather than on comparing and matching literal text. In most cases, it performs pattern matching rapidly and efficiently. However, in some cases, the regular expression engine can appear to be very slow. In extreme cases, it can even appear to stop responding as it processes a relatively small input over the course of hours or even days.

The performance of a regular expression is based on the length of the string and the complexity of the regular expression. Regarding your string `data`, I have prepared a [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4jYteV) here.

The code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var data = "[0].meetingDate=2019-07-12&[0].courseId=12&[0].raceNumber=1&[0].horseCode=000000331213&[1].meetingDate=2019-07-12&[1].courseId=12&[1].raceNumber=1&[1].horseCode=000000356650";
         var dataRegex=data+"&";
         //Console.WriteLine(dataRegex);
         showMatch(dataRegex, @"(?<==)(.*?)(?=&)");
    }

     private static void showMatch(string text, string expr) {
         MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);

         foreach (Match m in mc) {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
         }
      }
}
```

And the output is:

```
2019-07-12
12
1
000000331213
2019-07-12
12
1
000000356650
```

Regular expression used: `(?<==)(.*?)(?=&)`

Explanation:

1. Positive Lookbehind `(?<==)`: Matches the character `=` literally (case sensitive)
2. 1st Capturing Group `(.*?)`: `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators). `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed.
3. Positive Lookahead `(?=&)`: Matches the character `&` literally (case sensitive)